# pandas - merge rows based on column meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements

I'm new to pandas and I don't know the best way to do this.

I have two files which I've placed in two different dataframes:

```
>> frame1.head()
Out[64]:

    Date and Time           Sample  Unnamed: 2
0   05/18/2017 08:38:37:490 163.7   NaN
1   05/18/2017 08:39:37:490 164.5   NaN
2   05/18/2017 08:40:37:490 148.7   NaN
3   05/18/2017 08:41:37:490 111.2   NaN
4   05/18/2017 08:42:37:490 83.6    NaN


>>frame2.head()
Out[66]:
Date and Time               Sample  Unnamed: 2
0   05/18/2017 08:38:38:490 7.5 NaN
1   05/18/2017 08:39:38:490 7.5 NaN
2   05/18/2017 08:40:38:490 7.5 NaN
3   05/18/2017 08:41:38:490 7.5 NaN
4   05/18/2017 08:42:38:490 7.5 NaN
```

I need to "merge" any row from frame 1, with any row in frame 2, that are within one second of each other.

For example, 
this row from frame 1:

```
0   05/18/2017 08:38:37:490 163.7   NaN
```

is within one second of this row from frame 2:

```
0   05/18/2017 08:38:38:490 7.5 NaN
```

So when they are "merged" The output should be like this:

```
0   05/18/2017 08:38:37:490 163.7 7.5 NaN NaN
```

in other words, one row has it's time replaced by the other, and the all of the remaining columns are just appended

The closest I've come up with is to do something like:

```
    d3 = pd.merge(frame1, frame2, on='Date and Time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS:sss)', how='outer')

>>d3.head()
    Date and Time           Sample_x    Unnamed: 2_x    Sample_y    Unnamed: 2_y
0   05/18/2017 08:38:37:490 163.7   NaN NaN NaN
1   05/18/2017 08:39:37:490 164.5   NaN NaN NaN
2   05/18/2017 08:40:37:490 148.7   NaN NaN NaN
3   05/18/2017 08:41:37:490 111.2   NaN NaN NaN
4   05/18/2017 08:42:37:490 83.6    NaN NaN NaN
```

**But, that isn't a conditional merge**.. .I need to merge if they are within one second of each other, not just exactly the same.

I know I can compare the times with something like:

```
def compare_time(temp, sec=1):
   return abs(current - temp) <= datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec)
```

then use  .apply() or something... but I have no idea how to piece all this together

**EDIT:** it looks like pd.merge_asof does a good job, but I also need to retain the lines that aren't matched / merged in the final frame as well

**EDIT 2:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'datetime':pd.date_range('1-1-2017', periods= 4,freq='s'),
                     'sample':  np.arange(4)+100 })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'datetime':pd.date_range('1-1-2017', periods=4,freq='300ms'),
                     'sample':  np.arange(4) })

blah = pd.merge_asof( df2, df1, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )  \
    .append(df1.rename(columns={'sample':'sample_x'})).drop_duplicates('sample_x')
blah
```

returns:

```
    datetime    sample_x    sample_y
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 0   100.0
1   2017-01-01 00:00:00.300 1   100.0
2   2017-01-01 00:00:00.600 2   100.0
3   2017-01-01 00:00:00.900 3   100.0
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 100 NaN
1   2017-01-01 00:00:01.000 101 NaN
2   2017-01-01 00:00:02.000 102 NaN
3   2017-01-01 00:00:03.000 103 NaN
```

Notice it's retaining the original row indexes (zero is listed twice)..

Comment: You can check `pd.merge_asof` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof

Comment: How large in row size are each dataframe?

Comment: If r1 has a timestamp of `05/18/2017 08:38:37:490`, r2 has a timestamp of `05/18/2017 08:39:36:490`, and r3 has a timestamp of `05/18/2017 08:40:35:490`, how would they be merged?  r1 and r2 are within a second and r2 and r3 are also within a second.  but r1 and r3 are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge_asof` as @Wen suggests, but be sure to specify the optional value for `tolerance`.  Also consider the setting the option value for the `direction` of your match which can be 'backward' (default), 'nearest', or 'forward'.

```
pd.merge_asof( df1, df2, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )
```

Here's a longer explanation with sample data (Note I'm just creating new sample data since I can only see the first few rows of your actual data):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'datetime':pd.date_range('1-1-2017', periods= 4,freq='s'),
                     'sample':  np.arange(4)+100 })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'datetime':pd.date_range('1-1-2017', periods=4,freq='300ms'),
                     'sample':  np.arange(4) })

df1
Out[208]: 
             datetime  sample
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00     100
1 2017-01-01 00:00:01     101
2 2017-01-01 00:00:02     102
3 2017-01-01 00:00:03     103

df2
Out[209]: 
                 datetime  sample
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000       0
1 2017-01-01 00:00:00.300       1
2 2017-01-01 00:00:00.600       2
3 2017-01-01 00:00:00.900       3

pd.merge_asof( df1, df2, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )
Out[210]: 
             datetime  sample_x  sample_y
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00       100       0.0
1 2017-01-01 00:00:01       101       3.0
2 2017-01-01 00:00:02       102       NaN
3 2017-01-01 00:00:03       103       NaN
```

Note that `merge_asof` does a left join so you can get a different answer by changing the order of df1 & df2:

```
pd.merge_asof( df2, df1, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )
Out[218]: 
                 datetime  sample_x  sample_y
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000         0       100
1 2017-01-01 00:00:00.300         1       100
2 2017-01-01 00:00:00.600         2       100
3 2017-01-01 00:00:00.900         3       100
```

**Edit to add:**  the docs say `merge_asof` does a left join by design but it seems to differ from a true left join in that it excludes rows in the left dataframe that don't match.  To fix that you could do something like this:

```
pd.merge_asof( df1, df2, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )  \
    .append(df1.rename(columns={'sample':'sample_x'})).drop_duplicates('sample_x')
Out[236]: 
             datetime  sample_x  sample_y
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00       100       0.0
1 2017-01-01 00:00:01       101       3.0
2 2017-01-01 00:00:02       102       NaN
3 2017-01-01 00:00:03       103       NaN
```

Note that you may need to adjust `drop_duplicates` based on whether or not you have a unique index and/or unique columns.

Comment: how can I keep rows df2.2 and df2.3 as well? Looks like time ending in .6  are missing from the resulting data frame.

Comment: how can I retain rows that aren't merged? Notice in the merged result, that sample values 101, 102, 103 are missing

Comment: `blah = pd.merge_asof( df2, df1, on='datetime', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') )  \
    .append(df1.rename(columns={'sample':'sample_x'})).drop_duplicates('sample_x')` (reversed order of d2, d1) looks like it does what I want but it has this odd effect where there are multiple rows with index zero.. (I'll post it in an edit_

Comment: @JillRussek   Sorry not following exactly.  I see you swtiched the order of df2 & df1 in the merge, so you may need to switch sample_x to sample_y but I can't quite figure out exactly the final output you are going for